# Why my black box is not moving when I press my arrow key?

Tags: html, css

Could someone see, what is wrong with my code and guide me from there, as I'm new to the HTML and CSS? Everything is working perfectly until the `case` part. When I press the arrow key, the box is not moving. I believe somewhere has a problem to it.

```js
 window.addEventListen("keydown", press001, true);
 function press001(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
       case 37:
        dx = -1;
        dy = 0;
       break;
       case 38:
        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
       break;
       case 39:
        dx = 1;
        dy = 0;
       break;
       case 40:
        dx = 0;
        dy = 1 ;
       break;
    }
 };
```

Comment: First thing is what does your console say about that code?

Comment: Have you tried changing `addEventListen` to `addEventListener` @ChlongWilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, the most probable reason for this to fail is that you are using `addEventListen` instead of `addEventListener`. The easiest way to verify this is to open your Chrome console and try to add the following code

```js
window.addEventListen("keydown", function() { return true; }, true);
```

When you press enter you'll get the following error.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: window.addEventListen is not a function
```

So basically to fix your code you should do:

```js
 function press001(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
       case 37:
        dx = -1;
        dy = 0;
       break;
       case 38:
        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
       break;
       case 39:
        dx = 1;
        dy = 0;
       break;
       case 40:
        dx = 0;
        dy = 1 ;
       break;
    }
 };

window.addEventListener("keydown", press001, true);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I manage to program it.